# Change bot user name in slack for dialogflow bot

Tags: node.js, bots, slack, dialogflow-es

I am recently working on dialog flow bot (API.ai)

I have integrated my chatbot with slack from API.ai. When I start conversation and continue chatting, I found that bot username displayed in slack shown as *Dialog flow Bot*. But I have configured the name as *treselle*. How to change it?

Please find the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes! you can change it.

- Go to your slack chatbot application.
- Click on about tab.
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8c8l.png)
- Click on settings button.
- Below "Bot user", select **edit bot name** button beside the bot name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's possible or at least I couldn't make it neither.

If you're a developer too, here is what you can do:

- create a Slack app and bot, with enabled events subscriptions that will call your application webhook each time a message is sent to your bot
- create a DialogFlow agent that you will call using 'query' API
- create your own web application with a webhook route called by Slack, from which you can call DialogFlow API

This way you'll be able to customize every single details, including username, description, icon of the Slack bot, and send messages with rich content!

Here are more details: https://blog.eleven-labs.com/en/en/replace-erp-by-slack-bot-with-dialogflow-and-symfony/

Comment: yes, I tried this way, but bot name is not changing. but for bot created using AWS LEX, MS BOT frame work. i can able to customize it.. can you give me some more details? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same thing. Apparently you can't change the name of the bot until it is public. Here's a quote from the documentation...

> Once logged in, navigate to the instance and locate the bot user called @dialogflow-bot.
>
> Note: In order to change the name of the agent or add a logo, you'll need to make the bot public.

https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/slack